# SQL Transpose and group some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I want to transpose and group some columns from:

```
Agent     Date       Interval     EmailTime     PhoneTime
John      1-1-2017    00:00        00:15:00      NULL
John      1-1-2017    00:15        00:10:00      00:05:00
John      1-1-2017    00:30        NULL          00:15:00
```

To:

```
Agent     Date       Interval      State          Duration
John      1-1-2017    00:00        EmailTime      00:15:00
John      1-1-2017    00:15        EmailTime      00:10:00
John      1-1-2017    00:15        PhoneTime      00:05:00
John      1-1-2017    00:30        PhoneTime      00:05:00
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

you dont need a pivot. it can be achieved with a union all query.

```
Select Agent, Date, Interval    'EmailTime' State,  EmailTime     from table where EmailTime is not null 
union all 
Select Agent, Date, Interval    'PhoneTime' State,  PhoneTime     from table where PhoneTime is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code blcok:

`select agent
      ,date
      ,interval 'EmailTime'  as state
      ,emailtime as duration
  from table
 where emailtime is not null
union all
select agent
      ,date
      ,interval 'PhoneTime'  as state
      ,phonetime as duration
  from table
 where phonetime is not null
union all
select agent
      ,date
      ,interval 'NULL'  state
      ,phonetime as duration
  from table
 where emailtime is null
   and phonetime is null`